# interface inheriting multiple interfaces: how is this handled by a C# compiler?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, mono

Recently I found out that C# allows for

> [An interface can inherit from one or more base interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/87d83y5b.aspx).

For instance, the `IScreen` in Caliburn.Micro does this in http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Caliburn.Micro/IScreen.cs

```
namespace Caliburn.Micro
{
    public interface IScreen : IHaveDisplayName, IActivate, IDeactivate, 
        IGuardClose, INotifyPropertyChangedEx
    {
    }
}
```

I get why this is useful, as it implies that a class implementing `IScreen` also needs to implement the other interfaces.

But I wonder how the C# handles that compiler and run-time wise.

A little background/context of this question:

I come from a background where interfaces define a method-table, and that classes implementing interfaces have both their own method table, and pointers to the method tables of the interfaces they implement.

Sub questions swirling my mind stem from various multiple class inheritance discussions I had with people in the past, of which I think they apply to this case as well:

- Having an interface be able to inherit from multiple base interfaces, how would the order of methods in that table be?
- What if those interfaces have common ancestors: would those methods appear multiple times in the table?
- What if those interfaces have different ancestors, but similar method names?

(I'm using the word methods here, implying that a property defined in an interface will have a get_ or set_ method).

Any insight into this is much appreciated, as well as tips on how to phrase this question better.

Comment: Is your question about how this is represented at runtime in the CLR? Or how the compiler enforces it?

Comment: All of your bullets only apply to a concrete class, an interface does not inherit any implementation, has no table and has no methods.  The mapping of an interface method to the concrete method that implements it is done dynamically at runtime and doesn't occur until the method is called.  The plumbing underneath is very substantial, one of the few places in the CLR where assembly code is used.

Comment: @HansPassant: These fleeting glimpses into the deep internals you offer are maddening! :-) Can you offer a link to related CLR resources? Where do you get this information from? If it's original research, do you publish the results anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant +1; thanks for this. I'm originally from a part of the the native side where an interface does have a method table in order to have COM compatibility.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, let's be explicit in saying that "interface inheritance" is not quite the same thing as class-based inheritance (and using the word "inheritance" for both is perhaps misleading).

That's because interfaces cannot be instantiated on their own, so the compiler/runtime pair does not have to keep track of how to make a virtual call for standalone interface types (e.g. you don't need to know how to call `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` -- you just need to know how to call it *on a specific type of object*). That allows for handling things differently at compile time.

Now I don't actually *know* how the compiler implements "interface inheritance", but here's how it could be doing it:

> Having an interface be able to inherit from multiple base interfaces,
>   how would the order of methods in that table be?

It's not necessary for the "derived" interface to have a method table that includes the methods from all of its ancestor interfaces because it does not actually implement any of them. It's enough for each interface type to only have a table of methods it defines itself.

> What if those interfaces have common ancestors: would those methods
>   appear multiple times in the table?

Given the answer to the previous question, no. In the end a concrete type will only implement `IFoo` just once, regardless of how many times `IFoo` appears in the "hierarchy" of implemented interfaces. Methods defined in `IFoo` will only appear in `IFoo`'s bookkeeping tables.

> What if those interfaces have different ancestors, but similar method
>   names?

Again, no problem. You need appropriate syntax to tell the compiler "here's how to implement `IFoo.Frob` and here's `IBar.Frob`", but since methods of `IFoo` and `IBar` will be mapped in separate tables there are no technical issues.

Of course this leaves the question "how are methods dispatched at runtime?" unanswered. But it's not that difficult to imagine a possible solution: each concrete type `C` has pointers to one method table per interface it implements. When it's time to make a virtual method call the runtime looks at the concrete type, finds the table for the interface whose method is going to be called (the type of the interface is known statically) and makes the call.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm coming from the a place in the native world where interfaces must be able to map to COM interfaces, so there they have tables (and cannot inherit from multiple base interfaces). Your answer is very enlightening, but I still wonder how the CLR can have multiple vtables per interface. I came across http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S12 which is .NET 1.1 state of affairs, and http://monoruntime.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/interface-method-dispatch-im-table-and-thunks/ which is mono, and both seem to not support interfaces inheriting multiple base types.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to speak to how the official CLR does it.. but the Rotor distribution aggresively overlays common interface ancestors on top of one another in an objects vtable. It also allocates extra SLOTs into the concrete objects vtable where appropriate thereby reducing the need to jump from concrete type to interface vtable and then to the implementation.. the method offset is calculated at JIT time. If this optimization cannot be performed, then a single method can occupy the vtable more than once.

So the answer is (in regards to Rotor anyway), that it really is an implementation detail and any overlaying/optimizations etc are left completely up to what the compiler decides is best at the time it compiles the type.